# UnsatisfiedLinkError while porting Libgdx game to RoboVM com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Face.getSize(Native Method)

Tags: ios, libgdx, porting, robovm

**Project setup:**

- GameProject [This project holds game code]
- GameProject-Android
- GameProject-Desktop
- GameProject-robovm [this is a robovm project working perfectly without any free type font usage]

**robovm.xml content:**

```
<config>
  <executableName>${app.executable}</executableName>
  <mainClass>${app.mainclass}</mainClass>
  <os>ios</os>
  <arch>thumbv7</arch>
  <target>ios</target>
  <iosInfoPList>Info.plist.xml</iosInfoPList>
   <resources>
    <resource>../Grid Puzzle-android/assets/data</resource>
  </resources>
  <libs>
    <lib>/Users/pgs/Desktop/eclipse workspace/libgdx/gdx/libs/ios32/libgdx.a</lib>
    <lib>/Users/pgs/Desktop/eclipse workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-freetype/libs/ios32/libgdx-freetype.a</lib>
  </libs>
  <frameworks>
    <framework>UIKit</framework>
    <framework>OpenGLES</framework>
    <framework>QuartzCore</framework>
    <framework>CoreGraphics</framework>
  </frameworks>
</config>
```

**When running the robovm project it shows following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Face.getSize(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Face.getSize(Native Method)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeType$Face.getSize(FreeType.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateData(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator.generateFont(FreeTypeFontGenerator.java)
    at com.pechas.libgdx.font.FontControllerFreeType.loadFont(FontControllerFreeType.java)
    at com.pechas.libgdx.font.FontControllerFreeType.addFont(FontControllerFreeType.java)
    at com.pechas.libgdx.font.FontControllerFreeType.loadFonts(FontControllerFreeType.java)
    at com.pechas.libgdx.font.FontControllerFreeType.(FontControllerFreeType.java)
    at com.pechas.environments.Environment2D.(Environment2D.java)
    at com.pechas.platforms.platformLibgdx.create(platformLibgdx.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(IOSGraphics.java)
    at org.robovm.cocoatouch.uikit.UIView$Callbacks.draw(UIView.java)
    at org.robovm.cocoatouch.uikit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(Native Method)
```

Did anyone port a game with Freetype font usage to RoboVM?
Any guide to this problem...?

Question link at other sites:

- Libgdx forum link: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9960
- Robovm google group: This question is also posted at RoboVM google group.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in RoboVM's native method name mangler. The $ character isn't handled correctly. I've filed a report here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/120.